# getting updated receipent and email body information from MFMailComposeViewController class

Tags: iphone, web-services, json, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Is it possible to get **updated** receipent and email body information from  MFMailComposeViewController in iphone sdk manually. And manually sending that data in json web service to my own mail box.

Regards,
sathish

Answer (score 0):

From the Apple API:

Important: The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application. In addition, after presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make further changes to the email content. The user may still edit the content using the interface, but programmatic changes are ignored. Thus, you must set the values of content fields before presenting the interface.

Looking at this, and also trying out various names that would be appropriate for the ivars in the didFinishWithResult: method, it seems it is NOT possible to get this information from the prebuilt MFMailComposeViewController

you could subclass this class or roll your own to get the functionality..but that seems to be the only way to do it.